# Owl-carousel and Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

I want to use the bootstrap modal when I click on the owl-carousel elements, but my code only works for the mobile version and breaks down on the desktop.

```
$('.loop').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  navText:["",""],
  margin:40,
  responsive:{
    0:{
      nav:true,
      items:1
    },
    768:{
      nav:true,
      items:3
    },
    992:{
      nav:true,
      items:4
    }
  },
});

$('.loop .owl-item').on('click', () => {
 $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

I noticed that if I write "nav: false", a modal works, but I need navigation.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Enena/pen/eYpKZMr